# Nginx and php-fpm docker compose

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a development environnement for PHP project with Docker-compose.

I just created a docker-compose file that contains 3 docker:

- Application: that mounts my code volume
- Php: that runs php5-fpm
- Nginx: that runs the nginx web server.

I can get an html file through my web server but when I try with a php file I get a 502 Bad Request error.

Error.log:

```
2016/09/19 16:51:18 [error] 8#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: xxx, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.3:9000", host: "xxx"
```

I think that nginx can't connect to php.

Here is my **docker-compose** file:

```
# import the code and bind it on /var/www
application:
  build: code
  volumes:
    - ./sites:/var/www/
  tty: true

# php container
php:
  build: php-fpm
  volumes_from:
    - application
  expose:
    - 9000:9000
  volumes:
    - ./logs/php5-fpm/:/var/log

# nginx container
nginx:
  build: nginx
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - php
  volumes_from:
    - application
  volumes:
    - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

**php-fpm/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-common php5-cli php5-fpm php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-gd php5-imagick php5-curl php5-intl php5-memcache php5-imap

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

CMD ["php5-fpm", "-F"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

**nginx/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx
ADD test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

CMD ["nginx"]

EXPOSE 80
```

**nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log off;
  error_log off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

daemon off;
```

**nginx/test.conf:**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name xxx;
  root /var/www/test;

  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/test_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/test_access.log;
}
```

There is no error when launching the docker-compose.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Is php-fpm listening on `ip:port` or `unix socket` ?

Comment: Hello,

Yes, that was the problem, I didn't edited the _/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf_ file. It was listening on a unix socket (by default).

I added this line to my dockerfile:
`RUN sed -i 's/listen = \/var\/run\/php5-fpm.sock/listen = 0.0.0.0:9000/g' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

And it works well now ! Thank you !

Comment: @M4x0w post your solution as an answer and accept it.